# how to import seed module in javascript gnome-shell extension

Tags: javascript, c, seed, gnome-shell

It's quite simple: My js is part of a gnome-shell extension and contains several import lines:

```
[...]
const Gettext = imports.gettext;
const MessageTray = imports.ui.messageTray;
imports.searchPath.push("/opt/tempmon/lib"); // append custom search path
const Helper = imports.tempmon; // import helper module
[...implementation...]
```

I've compiled my shared lib with **seed-module.h** successfully and placed it under **/opt/tempmon/lib/libseed_tempmon.so**

Looking Glass (lg) displays:

> gjs/seed (I'm confused) couldn't find the "JS-Module tempmon in search path".

What action is needed to get my module included in the JS environment?